# Need help ordering these results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this query, and it runs fine, but I want to order based on the closest results first:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT Name, Address, City, State, Zip FROM Clinics WHERE ZIP IN 
   (SELECT h.zipcode FROM zipcodes 
    g JOIN zipcodes h on g.zipcode <> 
    h.zipcode AND g.zipcode = '32244' AND h.zipcode <> '32244'
     WHERE g.GeogCol1.STDistance(h.GeogCol1)<=(100 * 1609.344)) 
    UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT Name, Address, City, State, Zip 
    FROM Clinics WHERE ZIP = '32244'
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name, Address, City, State, Zip FROM Clinics 
WHERE ZIP IN (SELECT h.zipcode FROM zipcodes 
g JOIN zipcodes h on g.zipcode <> 
h.zipcode AND g.zipcode = '32244' AND h.zipcode <> '32244'
WHERE g.GeogCol1.STDistance(h.GeogCol1)<=(100 * 1609.344)) 
UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT Name, Address, City, State, Zip
FROM Clinics WHERE ZIP = '32244' 
order by g.GeogCol1.STDistance(h.GeogCol1) DESC
```

but it gives me an error:
 **Cannot find either column "g" or the user-defined function or aggregate "g.GeogCol1.STDistance", or the name is ambiguous.**

Am i going about this right?

Comment: is this a function: g.GeogCol1.STDistance

Comment: @logixologist: it's a spatial column by the look of it.

Comment: I think they are trying to achieve this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd434647.aspx

Comment: `g` and `h` are both out of scope by the time you reference them in your `ORDER BY` clause (this is much easier to spot in a more organized query). You might be able to rewrite this query with a few `JOIN`s, such that the information is still available for sorting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to establish the distance:

```
SELECT h.zipcode, (g.GeogCol1.STDistance(h.GeogCol1) / 1609.344) dist
  FROM dbo.zipcodes h CROSS JOIN dbo.zipcodes g
 WHERE g.zipcode = '32244'
```

This will pair the zip code in question with all zip codes, including itself. (I included the join to the same zip code because that saves me from having to do the `UNION` later.)

Next step is to filter on distance:

```
WITH ZipPairs AS(
  SELECT h.zipcode, (g.GeogCol1.STDistance(h.GeogCol1) / 1609.344) dist
    FROM dbo.zipcodes h CROSS JOIN dbo.zipcodes g
   WHERE g.zipcode = '32244'
), CloseZips AS(
  SELECT *
    FROM ZipPairs
   WHERE Dist < 100*1609.344
)
SELECT * FROM CloseZips;
```

After that you can join to the clinics and sort by distance:

```
WITH ZipPairs AS(
  SELECT h.zipcode, (g.GeogCol1.STDistance(h.GeogCol1) / 1609.344) dist
    FROM dbo.zipcodes h CROSS JOIN dbo.zipcodes g
   WHERE g.zipcode = '32244'
), CloseZips AS(
  SELECT *
    FROM ZipPairs
   WHERE Dist < 100*1609.344
)
SELECT C.*,Z.Dist
  FROM dbo.Clinics AS C
  JOIN CloseZips Z
    ON C.Zip = Z.zipcode
 ORDER BY Z.Dist;
```

Comment: great answer!!! I'm just noting this for future people who need help with your code. You misspelled CROSS AND to get the actual miles it should be (g.GeogCol1.STDistance(h.GeogCol1)/1609.344) dist